# jBPM 6.2 How to add an user that can execute all tasks?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

In jBPM 6.2, we can assign an user task to either an `actor` or a `group` such that they are the potential owners of these tasks. Is there an user that we can define in code or bpmn file so that he can execute all the user tasks regardless of the fact that the task is assigned to him or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a user with the username "Administrator", or use one of your existing users and add it to the group "Administrators". This gives the user(s) in question access to the task as Business Administrator. This should work for most of your requirements.

If you experience any challenges with this approach, another option could be to implement your own custom task assignment behavior in the 'Human Task' `WorkItemHandler`, but let's first try the approach mentioned above.

As requested a code example of this approach would be:

1. Implement a  class test.CustomHTWorkItemHandler that extends LocalHTWorkItemHandler (https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/wih/LocalHTWorkItemHandler.java).
2. Give it a new consuctor:

   ```
   public CustomHTWorkItemHandler(RuntimeManager runtimeManager){
          super.setRuntimeManager(runtimeManager);
   }
   ```
3. Override method createTaskBasedOnWorkItemParams:

   ```
   protected Task createTaskBasedOnWorkItemParams(KieSession session, WorkItem workItem) {
          InternalTask task =(InternalTask)super.createTaskBasedOnWorkItemParams(session,workItem);
          Group adminGroup = TaskModelProvider.getFactory().newGroup();
          ((InternalOrganizationalEntity) adminGroup).setId("MySpecialAdminGroup");        
          task.getPeopleAssignments().getBusinessAdministrators().add(adminGroup);
          return task;
   }
   ```
4. in your deployment descriptor XML file, register your new `CustomHTWorkItemHandler`:

   ```
   <work-item-handler>
          <resolver>mvel</resolver>
          <identifier>new test.CustomHTWorkItemHandler(runtimeManager)</identifier>
            <name>Human Task</name>
   </work-item-handler>
   ```

Comment: Can you please explain the part about implementing a custom task assignment behavior? Do you have a coding example on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Thanks Ampie for the example. It's very helpful. As a follow-up question if you don't mind, how can we use this custom human task handler in the jbpm model diagram? In other words, suppose I have a user task in my jbpm 6 model diagram, how can I use this custom handler for the user task? I tried to register the custom human task work item handler in the `kmodule.xml` file, but it's not being registered by jBPM.

Comment: My bad, I used the deployment descriptor syntax when referring to the kmodule file. I have modified the answer. Try the illustrated work-item-handler tag in the deployment descriptor xml (https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMRuntimeManagement.html#d0e11044) file. Unfortunately I can't test it myself at this point but do let me know if you encounter a problem.